# Why does the initState method of each page in TabBarView gets called every time a tab is changed

Tags: flutter

I would like to do some startup work on a page and I decided to put it in the `initState` method of a page however I noticed that every time I switch a tab the `initState` method  of various other pages included in the `TabBarView` get called even when those pages are not requested. Is this normal behavior ?  Currently the way I am handling to determine if the page is actually requested to be displayed is by reading the index value of `TabController` then performing the necessary initState work if needed. My question is am I handling this mechanism properly and also does the initState of each page get in the `TabBarView` get called whenever the tab changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so sure but I think what Flutter attempts to do is to ready nearby tab views (one before and after for example) so that when the user switches views it'll already be loaded and to minimize load times.